# Cypress Error: Failed to get 'appData' path

Tags: docker, jenkins, cypress

I'm getting below error when I run the cypress tests in Jenkins pipeline, but works fine locally. Should I set the appData in Dockerfile ? Is election missing write access ?

```
+ cypress run --browser chrome
[1m[47m[31mA JavaScript error occurred in the main process
[30mUncaught Exception:
**Error: Failed to get 'appData' path**
    at App.c._setDefaultAppPaths (electron/js2c/browser_init.js:5:1300)
    at Object.<anonymous> (electron/js2c/browser_init.js:185:2485)
    at Object../lib/browser/init.ts (electron/js2c/browser_init.js:185:3714)
    at __webpack_require__ (electron/js2c/browser_init.js:1:128)
```

Here's the Dockerfile.

```
ENV CI=1

ENV QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1
ENV _X11_NO_MITSHM=1
ENV _MITSHM=0

# should be root user
RUN echo "whoami: $(whoami)"
RUN npm config -g set user $(whoami)

# command "id" should print:
# uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
# which means the current user is root
RUN id

# point Cypress at the /root/cache no matter what user account is used
ENV CYPRESS_CACHE_FOLDER=/root/.cache/Cypress
RUN npm install -g "cypress@6.3.0"
RUN cypress verify

# Cypress cache and installed version
# should be in the root user's home folder
RUN cypress cache path
RUN cypress cache list

# give every user read access to the "/root" folder where the binary is cached
# we really only need to worry about the top folder, fortunately
RUN chmod 755 /root

CMD [ "cypress", "run"]
```

Here's the stage in jenkins;

```
stage('e2e cypress testing') {
    steps {
        withDockerContainer(args: '-v $PWD:/e2e -w /e2e', image: '<image name>') {
            // some block
        sh 'cypress-run'
        }
    }

}
```

Versions;

```
npm version: 6.14.11
Cypress package version: 6.3.0
Cypress binary version: 6.3.0
Electron version: 11.2.0
Bundled Node version: 12.18.3
```